# Error load new layer from query result

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0

I tried many times to create new layer from query result, but i got this error message, when loading it.

" PostgreSQL layer has no primary key."

```
    SELECT * FROM pgr_drivingDistance('select gid::int4 as id, source, target,
length_m as cost from public.ospr_ways', 24710, 1000
) AS routed1
INNER JOIN ospr_ways AS e
ON routed1.edge = e.gid::int4;
```

update: i have installed QGIS 3.10.5 LTR 64x, PostgreSQL 12 64x, PostGIS 3.0 for PostgreSQL 64X, Windows 10 64x
i already created postgis, pgrouting extension from pgAdmin for target database, and the query successfully executed and displayed it from pgAdmin, but i can't load my query as a new layer from db manager of QGIS.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add the complete version details of QGIS, PostGIS and pgRouting?

Comment: ok, i updated the question, please check it

Comment: Well, which field is supposed to be the primary key? Is that set?

Comment: Maybe try something like "ADD PRIMARY KEY (osm_id);"

Comment: Check `Colum(s) with unique values` and set to `seq`, or add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id` to the `SELECT`?

Comment: gid is a primary key from .ways

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/3NzgdmD/pk.png

Comment: But you are not loading *ways*; you are loading a query result, for which QGIS can't make out a unique id column by itself. Try naming one explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Layer added from query result successfully, after defining fields for query layer.

```
SELECT seq AS id, node as id1, edge AS id2, the_geom
FROM pgr_drivingDistance('select gid as id, source, target, cost_s
as cost from ways', 24710, 300) AS cadis 
JOIN ways AS e ON cadis.edge = e.gid;
```

Thank you @geozelot